# jQuery Uniform Checkbox does not (un)check

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox, append, uniform

I am using [jQuery Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/) to style inputs/selects etcs. However, the checkbox has stopped working. I am `appending` data sent from an ajax call. Once it's loaded, I use `$.uniform.update("input:checkbox")` to update the new html. When attempting to (un)check the input it works only once. If I want to (un)check it again, it doesn't change at all.

I've attempted changing the [Uniform Javascript](http://uniformjs.com/javascripts/jquery.uniform.js) so that all the actions (ie. `click`, `focus`, `blur` etc) are under the `.live` function. (ie. `.live("click",`). This just stops anything from working.

*Update:*

I've read through the Uniform JS entirely and discovered a problem:

```
if(!$(elem).attr("checked")){
    //box was just unchecked, uncheck span
    spanTag.removeClass(options.checkedClass);
}else{
    //box was just checked, check span.
    spanTag.addClass(options.checkedClass);
}
```

The `.attr("checked")` syntax fails. It will always return false. Why? I don't know. As well as this, it doesn't update the original `input` to either remove the `checked` attribute or to set the `checked` attribute.

I've run through the official website and found it doesn't update the checkbox input. So it's not just me xP

I've Googled around a bit and found various methods for checking if a checkbox is checked however the following methods fail:

```
if ($(elem).attr("checked")) // The original.
if ($(elem).attr("checked") == true)
if ($(elem).is(":checked"))
if ($(elem).checked)
// and:
var check = $(elem).match(/checked=/);
if (check == null)
```

Words of guidance are very much appreciated~ :3

Answer (score 67):

### SIMPLE SOLUTION

This is because [`UniformJs`](http://uniformjs.com/#docs) requires that you update your modification on uniform elements if you need to change values on the form dynamically:

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked',true);
$.uniform.update();
```

### Edit

If you wish to update the `#checkbox` only:

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked',true);
$.uniform.update('#checkbox');
```

Answer (score 30):

Just do this:

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked',true).uniform('refresh');
```

Comment: Old version 1.7.5 duplicates checkboxes, use $.uniform.update() instead, like @Mick mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

I know this may be a bit late, but hopefully it will help someone. I had to add a couple lines to the uniform code so it would look for pre checked checkboxes. This code starts at line 262 for me. I am using Uniform version 1.7.5. The lines between the 'added by John' notes are what I added.

```
        "click.uniform touchend.uniform": function(){
      if(!$(elem).attr("checked")){
        //box was just unchecked, uncheck span
        spanTag.removeClass(options.checkedClass);
      // Added by John to look for checkboxes with the attr "checked" that have been click to uncheck
      }else if(!$(elem).is(':checked')){
        spanTag.removeClass(options.checkedClass);
      // end addition by john
      }else{
        //box was just checked, check span.
        spanTag.addClass(options.checkedClass);
      }
    },
```

Comment: This doesn't work for jQuery 1.6.4, since `if(!$(elem).attr("checked")){` only checks if the checkbox was checked when the page was loaded.  This is different behaviour than previous versions of jQuery.  Use `prop` instead of `attr` to determine the _current_ status of "checked".

Comment: Excellent John tried Alex's method of changing .attr to .prop on my jquery.uniform.min file but did not fix the problem. Implemented your solution as well as add in Grants change and it worked a treat. Thanks guys. Using jQuery1.6.4 by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Its been a while but I had the same problem but I resolved it by a simple solution.

Uniform is adding a `span` over the checkbox and gives it the class `checked` if it is checked or not, but on page load only. If you check or uncheck the checkbox while the page is already loaded, it will uncheck (or check) but since the `span` is over it, you will see it as not updated, you have to do it manually.

```
$('#myDiv input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',true);
$('#myDiv input[type=checkbox]').parent().addClass('checked');
```

or

```
$('#myDiv input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
$('#myDiv input[type=checkbox]').parent().removeClass('checked');
```

Might not be the cleanest solution, but works fine on every browser.

Comment: This code works fine for me. Second line of code alone did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Hey Jean-Francois, this is because Uniform elements need to be updated after modification, I have posted an explanation [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637723/jquery-uniform-checkbox-does-not-uncheck/16516652#16516652).

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 1.6.4 changed the meaning of the `attr()` function, which is used by jquery.uniform.js.  `attr()` now returns the state that the attribute WAS in when the page loaded - not what the state of the attribute is NOW.  There is a replacement function called `prop()`, which does the job that `attr()` used to do.

To fix the plugin, replace each occurrence of `attr("checked")` with `prop("checked")`.  Also, change `attr("disabled")` to `prop("disabled")`.

That should fix your project up.  It worked for me ;-)

See also: https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/pull/167, which attempts to address the issue with better backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the latest version of Jquery uses a different method to evaluate a :checked value. Using a slightly older version (although not ideal) fixed this problem for me. That was a while ago though, and PixelMatrix still don't seem to have updated Uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use something like

```
$("#checkbox").attr("checked", "true");
```

to make the checkbox checked, and

```
$("#checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
```

to uncheck it?

Comment: These methods would work once a syntax has discovered if the element is already checked. Thanks anyway :D

Comment: Ahh, misunderstood the problem then :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change `.attr()` to `.prop()`:

```
    "click.uniform touchend.uniform": function(){
        if(!$(elem).attr('checked')){
            //box was just unchecked, uncheck span
            spanTag.removeClass(options.checkedClass);

            //Added by PingOn
            $(elem).removeAttr('checked');
            //end addition by PingOn

            // Added by John
        }else if(!$(elem).is(':checked')){
            spanTag.removeClass(options.checkedClass);
            // end addition by john

            //Added by PingOn
            $(elem).removeAttr('checked');
            //end addition by PingOn
        }else{
            //box was just checked, check span.
            spanTag.addClass(options.checkedClass);

            //Added by PingOn
            $(elem).attr('checked','true');
            //end addition by PingOn
      }
```