# uncheck checkbox with fnDrawCallback for DataTables

Tags: datatables

I have a checkbox in the thead of my table.  If the datatable is redrawn (by filtering, searching, pagination, whatever) I want to make sure this is unchecked.

```
"fnDrawCallback": function() {
  $(".checkboxes").uniform();
  $(".table-checkbox input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', false);
  alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
}
```

The uniform call fixes a stylization problem within the datatable... the alert is just to to show after each redraw.

Does it matter that .table-checkbox is outside of the datatable and not dynamic (it is explicitly in the html of the thead)?  I just want to make sure it is always unchecked upon table redraw.

EDIT :

The following works... is there a better way to do this?  Apparently I need to call uniform on the thead as well to do this.

```
"fnDrawCallback": function() {
  $(".table-checkbox input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', false);
  $(".checkboxes").uniform();
  $(".group-checkable").uniform();
  alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that this is a general uniform problem. In the above you first uncheck the checkboxes by code, *then* reinitalizes all the checkboxes so they seem to be unchecked by code, but in fact they are just reinitialized / reuniformed'!

See this question (and answer) -> [**jQuery Uniform Checkbox does not (un)check**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637723/jquery-uniform-checkbox-does-not-uncheck)

The only code you should need is

```js
fnDrawCallback: function() {
   $(this).find('thead input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
   $.uniform.update();
}
```

If you are using sorting you should replace `fnDrawCallback` with `fnInfoCallback` since `fnDrawCallback` in that case will be fired even if you click on the checkboxes only!