# A checked checkbox is not displaying checked? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, browser, laravel-5

i have a problem where a checked checkbox is not displaying checked.

My view:

```
@if(in_array($searchgroup->id.','.$searchtag->id, session()->get('zoektermen')))
    {{ Form::checkbox($searchtag->naam,$searchgroup->id. ',' .$searchtag->id, true, ['class' => 'search-checkbox']) }} {{ $searchtag->naam }}
@else
    {{ Form::checkbox($searchtag->naam,$searchgroup->id. ',' .$searchtag->id, null,['class' => 'search-checkbox']) }} {{ $searchtag->naam }}
@endif
```

I'm using laravel collective.

I'm using this code on other places on the website in different scenario's, where this works perfectly and the checkboxes display checked.

I'm using firefox but i also tried safari, no difference.
[image]

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: *How many checks could a checkbox check if a checkbox could check checks?* ... sorry.

Comment: What's with the random error suppression on the conditionals? Is there any Javascript that's monkeying about with checkboxes that have the class `search-checkbox` (or similar)?

Comment: Its may be theme/template issue. Its not an issue of Laravel. Because in your screenshot its rendered as `checked = "checked"`

Comment: @CD001 hahaha, but no no javascript interfering with the checkboxes

Comment: @B.Desai Yes, but i use the almost the same code, to populate a checked checkbox on another page and that is working fine...

Comment: remove class from input ... try... if it works then the problem in css...

Comment: I noticed yesterday when I updated from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3, that even when not binding to a model with Form::, if you are passing 2 arrays to the templates, it appears like one of the arrays will "bind" if both arrays contain the same property name, in this case, is it possible that $searchgroup->id is overriding $searchtag->id?

No clue why/what they changed, it appears like some scoping issue/bug after Laravel 5.2.

Comment: @pAsh No change when i remove class

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example having checked checkbox or not depending on the say user status Active or Inactive

```
{!! Form::checkbox('status', 'Active',  ($userData->status == 'Active') ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ,['data-prompt-position' => 'centerRight','data-title'=>'Active']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have included "uniform.default.js" in your project, it can create such an issue. Please use the following code to resolve it.

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked',true).uniform('refresh');
```

Further reading: [jQuery Uniform Checkbox does not (un)check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637723/jquery-uniform-checkbox-does-not-uncheck)

Thanks.